# Error building android cloud endpoint in android studio: Ensure that you have installed a JDK

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to add a backend endpoint cloud module to my android studio application but when i try build the project I'm getting the following error:

```
Executing tasks: [:backend:compileJava, :mobile:compileDebugSources, :wear:compileDebugSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:backend:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':backend:compileJava'.
> Cannot find System Java Compiler. Ensure that you have installed a JDK (not just a JRE) and configured your JAVA_HOME system variable to point to the according directory.
```

I have my JDK set to 1.7 (Project Structure > SDK Location > JDK Location: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home) but still getting this error..

Ive have even tried to force the JDK location by adding this to my gradle.properties and local.properties but no luck:
    org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Android Studio Version: 1.1.0
Gradle Version: 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that there were duplicate java jar files that were copied in by yosemite install into /Library/Java/Extensions. Removing the jar files and restarting android studio fixed it:

```
cd /Library/Java/Extensions 
sudo rm -rf *.jar
```